# C# Selenium Webdriver "The path is not of a legal form."

Tags: selenium, browser-automation, c#, selenium-webdriver, .net

Running firefox portable (which I know used to work) is now producing an error "The path is not of a legal form." when trying to load profile.

```
var binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe");       
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
```

Any suggestions ?
It should load default profile.

Comment: I just loaded your exact code into a solution and it started up firefox and worked in Selenium C#.

Comment: "used to work" implies something changed somewhere.  Any updates take place?  Permission changes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and see if you still get the same error? Also rebuild your entire project to be sure.

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
```

Comment: I then get compile error:"Cannot declare a variable of static type 'System.IO.File'" Surely i am missing something here, this used to work, have tried a rebuild.

Comment: And how about if you just remove the @ in your FirefoxBinary call? It just needs a string, no? Also, sorry, the File code is for Java, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Quickly written block of code that navigates here and logs in using your code and it works. Your problem likely exists elsewhere in your code.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe");
        var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);



        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/c-selenium-webdriver-the-path-is-not-of-a-legal-form");
        driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".topbar-menu-links > a:nth-child(2)").Click();
        driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#se-signup-legend > p:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)").Click();
        Console.WriteLine("Insert email address please");
        driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".form-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)").SendKeys(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Insert password please");
        driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".form-bottom > div:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(1)").SendKeys(Console.ReadLine());
        driver.FindElementByCssSelector(".form-submit > input:nth-child(1)").Click();
    }
```